# PHP printing wrong date

Tags: php

PHP:

```
<?php echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($pet['pet_lost_date']));?>
```

Variable Value:-

```
[pet_lost_date] => 16/04/2017
```

Output:

```
01-01-1970
```

Please help me why I searched a lot but I found nothing helpful.

Why is it appearing the wrong date? Where is an Error?

And How can I count from given date to toady total days month and years?

Comment: Are you sure ? tested it and get me result <?php echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime('16/04/2017'));?>

Comment: Yes I am sure it happening

Comment: if `$pet['pet_lost_date']` is coming from a query, wouldn't you consider using [MySQL Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and make sure `$pet['pet_lost_date']` isn't empty before use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php `date()` doesn't recognise `dd/mm/yy` format

Do like below:-

```
<?php 
if(!empty($pet['pet_lost_date'])){
  echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$pet['pet_lost_date'])));
}
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/777593

***Using `date_diff()`:-***

https://eval.in/777610

Comment: but empty `$pet['pet_lost_date']` will return `01-01-1970` I believe, so he has to make sure his var isn't empty, wich can actually be, don't you think ?

Comment: @OldPadawan you are right, a empty check also needed

Comment: I'm pretty sure is var is empty though :)

Comment: How to count days different?

Comment: @Shah Rushabh get it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the date a bit differently:

```
$pet['pet_lost_date'] = "16/04/2017";
$pet['pet_lost_date'] = str_replace('/', '-', $pet['pet_lost_date']);
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($pet['pet_lost_date']));
```

Output:

```
16-04-2017
```